# Chrome extension reload files when location changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Trying to implement a Chrome extension which embeds right into the page through `content_scripts`.

The challenge I am facing is I am using angularjs with the extension and need to first create the divs and then add the controller names, then initiate the controller function. Eg:

```
var body = document.querySelector('body');
body.setAttribute('ng-controller', 'BodyCtrl');


app.controller('BodyCtrl', function ($scope, $http, PollPage, PageType) {
 ...
})
```

This works fine on reloading the page and when the site is navigating not through javascript. But some sites use JS to load the dom and change the url to do so, in an angularjs manner which makes it not initial the `... document.querySelector ...` code.

Trying to find a way to reload the extension, reload the files or reload all these functions upon the url changing. Suggestions?

I thought of doing a watch on DOM objects which is ridiculous and inefficient, but I am trying to find other ways to do it. I tried triggering a function that'd do this on location.pathname change:

```
function addContent(){
    var body = document.querySelector('body');
    body.setAttribute('ng-controller', 'BodyCtrl');
}
```

Which triggers then the page changes due to the JS taking a few ms to change the content in the page.

Comment: Define "location change"? Modification of `#url_fragment`?

Comment: Hi Mohamed, did you find a solution for this. I have run into the same issue